# ASP.NET - Mobile Site Master

Tags: asp.net

As part of my university project, I had to develop a front end website with HTML5 and make it responsive. Then for the back end programming, I had to continue with ASP.NET. After configuring everything, all seems to be working fine except when I switch to responsive mode (via inspect) and no button is working because of the unconfigured Site.Master.Mobile (I haven't touched a thing there) - What should I implement there? Should I paste the original Site.Master code there or what?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by front site with HTML5 and ASP.NET for back end programming?

Comment: @IrishChieftain Although we are learning PHP, we had this special project which we had to convert from HTML to ASP.NET (C#)

Answer (score 1):

[Get rid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081059/disable-aspnet-friendlyurls-mobile-redirect-for-tablets) of ViewSwitcher.ascx and Site.Mobile.Master from your default ASP.NET project - they are neither needed (1) nor desired (2):

(1) You only need Bootstrap to make your site responsive.

(2) These files employ user agent sniffing which is totally unreliable these days.

Once you have this done and your site compiling without them, study up on Bootstrap and integrate the Bootstrap assets into your ASP.NET project assets to get everything working. Learn to merge common Bootstrap assets into your master pages and regular pages in an intuitive manner.

I would start reading the [Bootstrap documentation](http://getbootstrap.com/). Use version 3 of Bootstrap - version 4 is still in aplha.