# In Visual Studio 2015 I would like to remove site.mobile.master

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, web

In my asp.net forms website, I would like to remove site.mobile.master from my website.  I would like to use just site.master.  Is this possible?  I used the default settings to build the site.  I don't have the skills to make a website with a login without using the default asp forms web build.  This, unfortunately, makes a mobile.master and a view switcher.  I want neither.  Thank you for looking at this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, this is possible. [Get rid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081059/disable-aspnet-friendlyurls-mobile-redirect-for-tablets) of ViewSwitcher.ascx and Site.Mobile.Master from your default ASP.NET project - they are neither needed (1) nor desired (2):

(1) You only need Bootstrap to make your site responsive.

(2) These files employ user agent sniffing which is totally unreliable these days.

Once you have this done and your site compiling without them, study up on Bootstrap and integrate the Bootstrap assets into your ASP.NET project assets to get everything working. In the more up-to-date templates, Bootstrap is already being used - have you checked?

I would start reading the [Bootstrap](http://getbootstrap.com/) documentation.

Comment: So I deleted the files the website still displays on my desktop, but not on mobile devices.  Sigh.  I am going to make the site live so you can see this.  Proverbs1816.com.  Thanks for taking the time to look at this.

Comment: Adding Bootstrap is not difficult. Use Nuget to bring it into your project and read the documentation on the Bootstrap site - just add a container and rows with the appropriate classes - not really difficult. Glad to help :)

Comment: Make sure you have removed any logic relating to ViewSwitcher and the Mobile master page.

Comment: Thanks again for your help.  The site uses bootstrap looks great...  Still, it only works now on a desktop.  If I could ask one more question:  How do I remove "logic"?  I got rid of the 6 files that were associated with the switcher and mobile master.  I am not sure what else I can delete.  It has to be hidden somewhere :)  I might just tell people they can only look at the site on a "Desktop"  J/K......

Comment: Ok I deleted the "routes" table and that seemed to fix it.  Now I have to fully qualify my links, but it is a small price to pay.  Thanks for getting me looking in the right direction.  :)

Comment: I can't replicate what you're experiencing because it seems like you're using an older version of VS which is creating mobile master and viewswitcher. Search (CTRL-SHIFT-F) the files in the App_Start folder and check the main master code-behind. You could simply use the debugger to step through it.

Comment: Put the routes back in, nothing to do with it. Remove FriendlyUrls instead if they are enabled. https://www.hanselman.com/blog/IntroducingASPNETFriendlyUrlsCleanerURLsEasierRoutingAndMobileViewsForASPNETWebForms.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I've had this issue as well even after removing my ViewSwitcher and Site.Mobile.Master. What solved it for me was going into the RouteConfig.cs file and removing the AutoRedirectMode line:

```
        var settings = new FriendlyUrlSettings();
        //settings.AutoRedirectMode = RedirectMode.Permanent;
        routes.EnableFriendlyUrls(settings);
```