# Hamburger Menu not showing on mobile devices

Tags: html, css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap-3, mobile-devices

I am using bootstrap 3.4.x, and for some reason my Menu is not visible on mobile devices. I am able to resize in browser and all is good, but viewing on a device nothing. View port is set in head tag, jquery is being loaded before bootstrap.  I can't for the life of me find the issue.  ???  Below is the desired result (site: [site in question](http://w3.hassondojo.ca))

[image: Desired result]

here is what mobile looks like:

[Menu is missing](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9MsCJ.png)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">  
<head><meta charset="utf-8" />
   <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    
 </head>
<body>
<form runat="server">
    <asp:ScriptManager runat="server">
        <Scripts>
            <%--To learn more about bundling scripts in ScriptManager see https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=301884 --%>
            <%--Framework Scripts--%>
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MsAjaxBundle" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="jquery" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="bootstrap" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebForms.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebForms.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebUIValidation.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebUIValidation.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="MenuStandards.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/MenuStandards.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="GridView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/GridView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="DetailsView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/DetailsView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="TreeView.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/TreeView.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebParts.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/WebParts.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="Focus.js" Assembly="System.Web" Path="~/Scripts/WebForms/Focus.js" />
            <asp:ScriptReference Name="WebFormsBundle" />
            <%--Site Scripts--%>
        </Scripts>
    </asp:ScriptManager>


 <div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
        <div class="container">
            <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#ham-menu">
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                    <span class="icon-bar"></span>
                </button>
                <a class="navbar-brand" runat="server" href="~/">LOGO Here</a>
            </div>
            <div class="navbar-collapse collapse">
                <ul class="nav navbar-nav" id="ham-menu">
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Schedule">Schedule</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Gallery">Gallery</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
                    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
                </ul>
                <asp:LoginView runat="server" ViewStateMode="Disabled">
                    <AnonymousTemplate>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Register">Register</a></li>
                            <li><a runat="server" href="~/Account/Login">Log in</a></li>
                        </ul>
                    </AnonymousTemplate>
                    <LoggedInTemplate>
                        <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
                            <li>
                                <a runat="server" href="~/Account/Manage" title="Manage your account">Hello, <%: Context.User.Identity.GetUserName()  %>!</a>

                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <asp:LoginStatus runat="server" LogoutAction="Redirect" LogoutText="Log off" LogoutPageUrl="~/" OnLoggingOut="Unnamed_LoggingOut" />
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </LoggedInTemplate>
                </asp:LoginView>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: As much as I was able to debug, removing "collapse" from "navbar-collapse collapse" can help you get the menu in mobile. Hope it helps :)

Comment: @krishna_tandon thank you, unfortunately, this did not fix issue.  :(

Comment: Can you update the same with the desired output? Maybe that can help us dive deep into the issue.

Comment: @krishna_tandon I have updated question and added images to reflect

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this article that worked.  make sure to take note on Olorunfemi Ajibulu comment at the bottom.  regrading remove additional files at destination!!

[Disable aspnet.friendlyurl's mobile redirect for tablets](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23081059/disable-aspnet-friendlyurls-mobile-redirect-for-tablets#comment97435089_52488979)

Answer (score 2):

**Update**: I checked the site link you have given in question. It seems everything is rendering fine. Now you just need to move the `id="ham-menu"` attribute.

So, I copy pasted your code on a page where bootstrap 3.4.x was initialized properly. Turns out your HTML Code is fine with only one problem:

Move the id attribute from `<ul>` to the outer `<div>`.

```html
<div class="navbar-collapse collapse" id="ham-menu"><!--To Here-->
  <ul class="nav navbar-nav"><!--From Here-->
    <li><a runat="server" href="~/">Home</a></li>
    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Schedule">Schedule</a></li>
    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Gallery">Gallery</a></li>
    <li><a runat="server" href="~/About">About</a></li>
    <li><a runat="server" href="~/Contact">Contact</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Now, make sure you have properly initialized bootstrap. Key points:

```html
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: I have tried move the ID, however this also did not work for me.  I even copied in the above links.  still no menu on mobile